# How does one populate a list in a class

Tags: c#, list

I have a simple class that has some properties, one property is a list.

```
public IList<CounterReclaimCardModels> CounterReclaimCards { get; set; }
public long AggID { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
```

I instantiated the class and added some data to it, but I cant figure out how to add data to the list. below is how I instantiated the class

Below is how I am instantiating the list and trying to add to it

```
 CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards = new List<CounterReclaimCardModels>()
        {
            CounterReclaimID = 1,
            ReclaimType = "Rule22Pool",
            ReclaimDisposition = "None",

        };
```

Comment: I wouldn't add inline like this as a list is intended to be added to dynamically. If you want to add stuff inline (hard coded) you might as well use an array. The list has an "add" function.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov I'm curious why you have that opinion? If I'm not mistaken, building a list this way will invoke the constructor which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`. IMO this is probably better than calling `Add(...)` after initialization.

Comment: @Yuck I wouldn't say its "better" to do it in the constructor or explicitly. Maybe it is cleaner at best. I guess what this person is trying to is setup default values. However if these are the only values that need to be in the collection, then having the overhead of using the list is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will put a single item of type `CounterReclaimCardModels` into a new list:

```
CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards = new List<CounterReclaimCardModels>
    {
        new CounterReclaimCardModels
        {
            CounterReclaimID = 1,
            ReclaimType = "Rule22Pool",
            ReclaimDisposition = "None",
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards = new List<CounterReclaimCardModels>()
{
    new CounterReclaimCardModels()
    {
        CounterReclaimID = 1,
        ReclaimType = "Rule22Pool",
        ReclaimDisposition = "None"
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a list, you can load it up with starting values like so:

```
CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards = new List<CounterReclaimCardModels>
{
    new CounterReclaimCardModels()
    {
        CounterReclaimID = 1,
        ReclaimType = "Rule22Pool",
        ReclaimDisposition = "None"
    },
    new CounterReclaimCardModels()
    {
        CounterReclaimID = 2,
        ReclaimType = "AwesomeThing",
        ReclaimDisposition = "None"
    },
    variableForAnExistingCounterReclaimCardModels,
    //etc...
};
```

Or, you can just use the Add method:

```
CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards = new List<CounterReclaimCardModels>();
CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards.Add(new CounterReclaimCardModels()
    {
        CounterReclaimID = 1,
        ReclaimType = "Rule22Pool",
        ReclaimDisposition = "None"
    });

CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards.Add(new CounterReclaimCardModels()
    {
        CounterReclaimID = 2,
        ReclaimType = "AwesomeThing",
        ReclaimDisposition = "None"
    });

CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards.Add(variableForAnExistingCounterReclaimCardModels);
```

Also, you can initialize the list with a few values, then use Add to add more later.

Answer (score 1):

You must create an instance of each item in list:

```
CounterReclaim.CounterReclaimCards = new List<CounterReclaimCardModels>()
{
    new CounterReclaimCardModels
    {
        CounterReclaimID = 1,
        ReclaimType = "Rule22Pool",
        ReclaimDisposition = "None"
    }
    // ...
};
```